# PostgreSQL Logical Replication Custom Column Expression

Tags: database, postgresql, expression, replication, reporting

I am experimenting with PostgreSQL15 logical replication.

I have a table called "test" in database "test1" with columns "id" int (primary) and "name" varchar

```
id int (primary) | name varchar
```

I also have a table called "test" in database "test0" with columns "tenant" int (primary), "id" int (primary) and "name" varchar

```
tenant int (primary/default=1) | id int (primary) | name varchar
```

I have the following publisher on database "test1"

```
CREATE PUBLICATION pb_test FOR TABLE test ("id", "name")
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test_slot_v1', 'pgoutput');
```

I also have the following subscriber database "test0"

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sb_test CONNECTION 'dbname=test1 host=localhost port=5433 user=postgres password=*********' PUBLICATION pb_test WITH (slot_name = test_slot_v1, create_slot = false);
```

The result is that every time a new record is added on the database "test1", then the same record is inserted on database "test0" with tenant=1 as is the default value.

The question, is there any way to have custom expression for this additional column "tenant" while being replicated? For example records coming from database "test1" should have tenant=1 but records coming from database "test2" will have tenant=2.

Comment: Adding an integer column into the subscriber table with a default value of 1 (for rows coming from the publisher) and forcing a 2 when inserted locally at the subscriber database

Comment: how you are going to force tenant=2 and tenant=3 while inserted from different subscribers?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are looking for but, having an extra column at the subscriber table (let's say `src int default 1`) let you differentiate if the rows come from the publisher or from the subscriber database. Rows coming from the publisher will have a default `1` value at `src`; rows inserted locally at the subscriber database can be forced to have  a `2` by including a `src = 2` on the insert/update SQL sentences.

Comment: practically the goal is to gather rows from multiple databases while the rows can be distinguished with tenant_id

Comment: Then force `tenant_id = 1` at node 1,  `tenant_id = 2` at node 2 on insert/update tables?

Comment: You may have to sligthly edit the insert/update sentences on every node

Comment: do you have any example how this can be done?

Comment: Add a `tenant_id int default #` column to every `test` table at every database. Replace `#` by `1` at database 1 and by `2` at database 2. Publish table `test` from database 1 and subscribe from database 2. Rows coming from database 1 will have `tenant_id=1`, while rows inserted locally at database 2 will have `tenant_id=2`. You don't even need to touch any sentence.

Comment: ahh, unfortunately i cannot do that, imagine this is not a solution when working with production erp systems, maybe i didn't mentioned that because currently i am experimenting on this.

Comment: How many publishers will converge on the subscriber table?

Comment: for now to test this, they can be two, but in production for sure it can be 50 or 100. Not sure if this is going to work, but before going to this topic i have these "structure" issues

Comment: Sounds more like an Apache Kafka scenario...

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70867403/kafka-connect-bidirectional-replication-between-2-databases

Comment: Could be yes, but from the moment that Postgres has invest on the logical replication why not to have these kind of benefits? It’s more clear solution to have this inside database.

Comment: Note that, if you cannot alter a table at the ERP databases, chances are you are not allowed to CREATE PUBLICATION either

Comment: I have no experience with 50-100 replicas, but it sounds complex enough to keep alive. I would suggest asking an expert in PostgreSQL about the scalability of the logical replication mechanism before going on.

Comment: As you said, I love PG logical replication for its simplicity and natural mechanism. I use it to implement CQRS among microservices, but never scaled to that point.

Comment: Yes, maybe it’s better to go with Azure Data Factory and classic old ETL style. Maybe is not streaming but with high frequency maybe can archive near to real time…

Comment: An ad hoc solution for a ad hoc problem? Sounds good. If the problem grows, affecting more tables, Kafka or something equivalent is worth the learning curve effort.

Comment: Good luck Stavros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that currently, PostgreSQL14 Logical Replication does not support this requirement to have additional columns with fixed values.

### UPDATE

PostgreSQL15 allows to publish and subscribe on subset of columns of a table but still is not supporting custom expression as key or value column